# Datapump error in log file

Tags: oracle

When I do this:

```
DECLARE
hdnl NUMBER;
BEGIN
hdnl := DBMS_DATAPUMP.open( operation => 'EXPORT', job_mode => 'TABLE', job_name=>null);
DBMS_DATAPUMP.ADD_FILE( handle => hdnl, filename => 'tab1.dmp', directory => 'DATA_PUMP_DIR', filetype => dbms_datapump.ku$_file_type_dump_file);
DBMS_DATAPUMP.add_file( handle => hdnl, filename => 'exp.log', directory => 'DATA_PUMP_DIR', filetype => dbms_datapump.ku$_file_type_log_file);
DBMS_DATAPUMP.METADATA_FILTER(hdnl,'SCHEMA_EXPR','IN (''USERS'')');
DBMS_DATAPUMP.METADATA_FILTER(handle => hdnl,name => 'NAME_EXPR',value => 'IN (''CA_FILE'')');
DBMS_DATAPUMP.start_job(hdnl);
END;
/
```

And I read:

```
select * from table(RDSADMIN.RDS_FILE_UTIL.READ_TEXT_FILE('DATA_PUMP_DIR','tab1.dmp'));
```

It gives me following:

```
Starting "AUSER"."SYS_EXPORT_TABLE_01":  
Estimate in progress using BLOCKS method...
Total estimation using BLOCKS method: 0 KB
ORA-31655: no data or metadata objects selected for job
Job "AGSUSER"."SYS_EXPORT_TABLE_01" completed with 1 error(s) at Tue Jan 26 20:28:37 2016 elapsed 0 00:00:01
```

I am trying to EXPORT 1 table. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This simply means you do not have any table called `USERS.CA_FILE`.